# Lua segfault on coroutine resume

Tags: c, lua, segmentation-fault

I have code

```
fun = function() 
    coroutine.resume(co); -- here it segfaults
    return true;
end ;

-- evtimer is my binding to libev
-- timer = evtimer.new(1,1, fun); -- this works ok and prints "co N" every second


co = coroutine.create(function ()
        timer = evtimer.new(1,1, fun); --this segfaults


         for i=1,100000 do
             print("co", i)
             coroutine.yield(111);
        end
end)
-- timer = evtimer.new(1,1, fun); -- this works too

coroutine.resume(co);

timer:start(); --start timer
-- here main thread ends and libev event loop starts. Timer callback is called by event loop
```

and variant when timer is created inside coroutine segfaults on resume inside lua core. Backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000066ec00 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x000000000066ec00 in ?? () 
#1  0x0000000000413430 in resume (L=0x6841a0, ud=0x6d8ac0) at ./src/myprogram/lua/ldo.c:522
#2  0x00000000004120e9 in luaD_rawrunprotected (L=0x6841a0, f=0x4132da <resume>, ud=0x6d8ac0)
    at ./src/myprogram/lua/ldo.c:131
#3  0x00000000004134ef in lua_resume (L=0x6841a0, from=0x6841a0, nargs=0)
    at ./src/myprogram/lua/ldo.c:543
#4  0x0000000000429b4e in auxresume (L=0x6841a0, co=0x6841a0, narg=0)
    at ./src/myprogram/lua/lcorolib.c:31
#5  0x0000000000429c5a in luaB_coresume (L=0x6841a0) at ./src/myprogram/lua/lcorolib.c:53
#6  0x0000000000412b19 in luaD_precall (L=0x6841a0, func=0x6d8aa0, nresults=2)
    at ./src/myprogram/lua/ldo.c:319
#7  0x0000000000424b2b in luaV_execute (L=0x6841a0) at ./src/myprogram/lua/lvm.c:709
#8  0x0000000000412f8a in luaD_call (L=0x6841a0, func=0x6d8a70, nResults=1, allowyield=0)
    at ./src/myprogram/lua/ldo.c:402
#9  0x000000000040c77a in f_call (L=0x6841a0, ud=0x7fffffffe000) at ./src/myprogram/lua/lapi.c:923
#10 0x00000000004120e9 in luaD_rawrunprotected (L=0x6841a0, f=0x40c73e <f_call>, ud=0x7fffffffe000)
    at ./src/myprogram/lua/ldo.c:131
#11 0x0000000000413722 in luaD_pcall (L=0x6841a0, func=0x40c73e <f_call>, u=0x7fffffffe000,
    old_top=112, ef=0) at ./src/myprogram/lua/ldo.c:603
#12 0x000000000040c84a in lua_pcallk (L=0x6841a0, nargs=0, nresults=1, errfunc=0, ctx=0, k=0x0)
    at ./src/myprogram/lua/lapi.c:949
#13 0x0000000000433a54 in lua_script_pcall (ls=0x6841a0, nargs=0, nresults=1)
    at ./src/myprogram//lua_script.c:41
#14 0x00000000004353b0 in lua_evtimer_callback (loop=0x66cc20 <default_loop_struct>, w=0x684938,
    revents=256) at ./src/myprogram//evtimer_lualib.c:21
#15 0x0000000000406d41 in ev_invoke_pending (loop=0x66cc20 <default_loop_struct>)
    at ./src/myprogram/libev/ev.c:2994
#16 0x000000000040763b in ev_run (loop=0x66cc20 <default_loop_struct>, flags=0)
    at ./src/myprogram/libev/ev.c:3394
```

it segfaults on line 522(lua 5.2)  n = (*ci->u.c.k)(L);  /* call continuation */

Is there anyone familiar with lua core? Why this happens?

Comment: Build Lua with assertions and API checking enabled, and be sure none of your C functions are doing something incorrect with the Lua API.

Comment: Thanks very much, i turned on api cheking and it helped me to find out problem. Assertion was lua/lapi.c:938: lua_pcallk: Assertion `(L->status == 0) && "cannot do calls on non-normal thread"' failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that i was saving current Lua_State in evtimer.new and called timer callback(with pcall) in context of thread where evtimer.new was called. 
In this case thread was not resumed when timer attempted to call callback and this caused corruption of lua internal state
I fixed it with using lua_resume on C side to resume thread instead of calling lua callaback